# How to attach users to an 'events' table in a database?

Tags: database, database-design

I apologize if someone else can readily find this question - I tried phrasing it a few different ways and didn't see an answer on SO.

I'm trying to create a mocked up social network - very simple, basically conceptual at this point. If a user creates an event to invite other users to, how do I attach the responded users to the database in the most meaningful way? In other words, what is the best way to do this such that the attached users are all query-able? I'm not, for instance, going to create a field called "users" and just keep appending user ID's to it.

So far, my table design looks something like this:

```
eventID (PK)
eventDate
eventTime
eventLocation
```

Now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to attach users and add a flag indicating which user(s) might be hosting.

I would love some feedback on design! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since more than one user can respond to an event invitation, you will need a separate table for "eventResponses". It could have a schema like:

```
eventID (FK)
userID (FK)
response (varchar(10)) -- Yes, No, Maybe, whatever
```

A uers's yes / no / maybe response to an event would be stored in this table. You can then look at how many responses a particular event has received.

Comment: Ahh! I hadn't considered a separate table for responses. This makes sense, thanks for your time!